# How to pass a component reference to onPress callback?

Tags: react-native

I did render following kind of list with onPress "handler".

[image]

I have realised that onPress handler is useless because I cannot get the reference of race pressed. I get ref is not defined error.

```
var races = Engine.possibleRaces;

function racePressed(ref) {
    console.log("REF: " + ref); // is never called
}

var races = Engine.possibleRaces;
var rowViews = [];
for (var i = 0; i < races.length; i++) {
  rowViews.push(
    <Text
      ref={i}
      onPress={() => racePressed(ref)} // ref is not defined
      style={styles.raceText}>{races[i].text}
    </Text>

  );
}

<View style={{width: Screen.width, flexDirection:'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: "center"}}>
       {rowViews}
</View>
```

I did also try to pass i as a parameter. It did not work, because it has the value after iteration ends. Basically it has races.length value.

```
  onPress={() => racePressed(i)} // Same as races.length
```

**Edit:**

I did isolate problem to following program.

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

let texts = [{text: "Click wrapper text1"}, {text: "Click wrapper text2"}];

class sandbox extends Component {

  rowPressed(ref, i) {
    console.log("rowPressed: " + ref + " " + i)
  }

  render() {

    var rows = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      rows.push(
        <Text
          ref={i}
          onPress={() => this.rowPressed.bind(this, i)}
          style={styles.raceText}>{texts[i].text}
        </Text>
      );
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View>
          {rows}
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('sandbox', () => sandbox);
```

Callback is not called and no errors thrown except following warning

```
[tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `sandbox`. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you bind that function in constructor like..

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //your codes ....

    this.rowPressed = this.rowPressed.bind(this);
}
```

This binds `this` context of rowPressed function as you expect it to be, making your code works properly.

Also, to get rid of warning messages you should provide unique `key` properties for each `<Text>` element, using `<Text key={i} ....>` in your code should work.

Comment: Could you share a bit more code. How should I change following code to the access to "this"?

`render: function() {
   function rowPressed(id) {
      // Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
      this.state.races[id].chosen != this.state.races[id].chosen;
   }
   this.rowPressed = this.rowPressed.bind(this);
   ...
   onPress={() => rowPressed(i)}`

Answer (score 3):

I try to do something similar and found this solution :

```
render() {
    var _data = texts;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        { _data.map(function(object,i) {
            return (
                <Text ref={i}
                  onPress={() => this.rowPressed(i)}
                  style={styles.raceText}>{texts[i].text}
                </Text> );
            })
        }
        </View>
    );
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I cannot use "this" expression in "this.rowPressed(i)" else I get "Cannot read property 'rowPressed' of undefined". I just need to use rowPressed and function is properly called. Now I have issue with the rowPressed function. I cannot get access to this.state anymore.
`function rowPressed(id) {
      this.state... // Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
}`

Comment: Following seems to work, but for some reason it feels not being properly done.
`var that = this;
    function rowPressed(id) {
      that.state.races[id].chosen = !that.state.races[id].chosen;`