# React-Native ViewPager goToPage Not Working

Tags: react-native

```
import ViewPager from 'react-native-viewpager';
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this._renderPage = this._renderPage.bind(this);
        this._renderRowSablon = this._renderRowSablon.bind(this);
        this.PageChange = this.PageChange.bind(this);
        this.count = 0;
        this.state = {
              count: 0,
              info : this.props.values,
              page: 0,
              pages:pages,
        }
 }
 PageChange(x){
        switch(x){
              case 'next':
                    if( this.state.count< (this.state.info.sayfa - 1) ){
                          this.viewpager.goToPage(this.state.count + 1);
                          this.setState({count: this.state.count+ 1});
                    }
              break;
        }
  }
render(){
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
               <ViewPager
                   ref={(viewpager) => {this.viewpager = viewpager}}
                   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                   renderPage={this._renderPage}
                   onChangePage={this._pageChange}
                    isLoop={false}
                   renderPageIndicator={false}
                   locked={true}
                   autoPlay={false}/>
             </View>
             <View style={{flex:1}}>
                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.PageChange('next'); }}>
                 <Text>Next</Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
             </View>
}
```

When the setState function is cleared, page change is taking place. When the setState function is added (as above) setState works but the page change (gotoPage) does not work. Does not show error / warning What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more information. Like more code, things you have tried, etc. Like, I would like to see your declaration of state in the constructor. Are you importing any classes? Where is the actual page you speak of. Is this android or ios?

Comment: I say that, because I sense that your question is about to recieve a lot of downvotes due to the ambiguity of it.

Comment: See this question about logging errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native

Comment: I tried to make it a little clearer. The console does not show any information. Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are out of scope. When using arrow functions, the scope of 'this' becomes lexical.

Try changing `<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.PageChange('next'); }}>`

to `<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.PageChange('next')}>`

See this question: 
[React-Native: Cannot access state values or any methods declared from renderRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262837/react-native-cannot-access-state-values-or-any-methods-declared-from-renderrow)

Comment: I think the problem will be resolved in this way. How do we just define this.ViewPager? The error shown is: undefined is not an object 'this.viewpager.goToPage'

Comment: Check the answer out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663375/how-to-pass-a-component-reference-to-onpress-callback

You would need to pass the `this` object to the function.

And your PassChange function would need to look something like:  `PageChange(x, this){`

Comment: Thanks Adam. The first problem was corrected. But I still have not solved the problem for viewPager.

Comment: Well, you should need a return statement inside of your render function? Unless I am missing it.

Comment: @Yavuz Civelek, does the goToPage() function exist? You probably need to make it, I can't find it defined anywhere. Like: `function goToPage(url){ if(url != ""){  go to URL here } }`
This stackoverflow question should guide you on how to get react native to open a url for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531679/react-native-open-links-in-browser

Comment: I just erased some parts to be able to ask shorter questions. :)

Comment: Library: https://github.com/race604/react-native-viewpager

GoToPage () is actually in this library.
This is not a problem when manually running goToPage.
I probably can not fully define the viewPager here.

Comment: Ok, I have an idea. Create a variable after your render function, like: var self = this; Then, make a function under that: var handleClick = function(this){ self.PageChange(x, this); } Then change your PageChange function to PageChange(x, this) Then make your button: <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClick('next', this)}>

Comment: "PageChange (x, this)" on this function generates 'this' error.
Unexpected Token

Comment: What happens if you make `<TouchableHighlight onPress={handleClick('next', this)}>`

I incorrectly added the this keyword. (Sorry, confusing problem)

Comment: It's a frustrating problem. I guess we could not solve the problem exactly :)